# solve ODE by homogeneous substitution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve ode by making substitution. $(x-y) dx + xdy=0$

Let $y = ux$ then $dy = xdu+udx $

$$xdx+(ux-2x)(xdu+udx)=0  \\
xdx+ux^2du+u^2xdx-2x^2du-2uxdx = 0  \\
xdx-2x^2du+ux^2du+u^2xdx-2uxdx=0  \\
xdx+u^2xdx-2uxdx-2x^2du+ux^2du=0  \\
(x+u^2x-2uxd)dx+(-2x^2+ux^2)du=0\\  
x(1+u^2-2u)dx=0x^2(u-2)du \\ 
(1+u^2-2u)dx=-x(u-2)du  \\
(1+u^2-2u)dx=-x(2-u)du  \\
\frac{dx}{-x}=\frac{2-u}{1+u^2-2u} du  \\
\frac{dx}{-x}=\frac{2-u}{(u-1)^2} du  $$

No clue what to do here.
This is problem 3 and the textbook gives one crappy example. Why is it so hard?

Answer (score 2):

Almost just as you started. Just rewrite $$(x-y)  + x\frac{dy}{dx}=0$$ and set $y=u x$ as you did. So, $$\frac{dy}{dx}=u+x\frac{du}{dx}$$ Replace in the equation; you should arrive to $$x \left(x \frac{du}{dx}+1\right)=0$$ that is to say $$x \frac{du}{dx}+1=0$$ which is separable.

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: Thanks I'm understanding it. How did you know to rewrite the original equation to have $\frac{dy}{dx}$, is that a step that should always be done?

Comment: For two reasons : first, because we look for $y(x)$, then its looks natural to me fo express the equation with $\frac{dy}{dx}$; second, just because I am old !! Cheers :-)

Answer (score 1):

$$(x-y) dx + xdy=0$$
$$\frac{x-y}{x^2} dx + \frac{1}{x}dy=0$$
$$\frac{x-y}{x^2} dx + \frac{1}{x}dy=0$$
$$\frac{1}{x}dx+\frac{xdy-ydx}{x^2} =0$$
$$d\ln(x)+d\frac{y}{x} =0$$
$$d\left(\ln(x)+\frac{y}{x}\right) =0$$
$$u:=\ln(x)+\frac{y}{x}\qquad\Rightarrow\qquad du=0$$

Comment: how did you know to divide by $x^2$?

Comment: I noticed the expression $xdy-ydx$, that is close to the formula for the differential of a ratio so I divided in order to obtain the second term in the fourth line. (If there were a + I'd simply use Leibniz rule).